# OpenACC with DGEMM call error in gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, cublas, openacc

gfortran has host_data support now, so I wanted to test DGEMM. Based on the test case posted here

[host_data patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2016-08/msg00976.html)

I wrote a sample code for DGEMM using cuBLAS.

```
program test

  use iso_c_binding

  implicit none

  integer(c_int), parameter :: N = 10
  integer(c_int) :: i, j
  real(c_double) :: x(N, N), y(N, N), z(N, N)
  character(kind=c_char)     :: flag

  interface
     subroutine cublasdgemm(transa, transb, m, n, k, alpha, A, lda, B, &
             ldb, beta, C, ldc) bind(c, name="cublasDgemm")
       use iso_c_binding
       character(kind=c_char)     :: transa, transb
       integer(kind=c_int), value :: m, n, k
       real(c_double), value      :: alpha
       type(*), dimension(*)      :: A
       integer(kind=c_int), value :: lda
       type(*), dimension(*)      :: B
       integer(kind=c_int), value :: ldb
       real(c_double), value      :: beta
       type(*), dimension(*)      :: C
       integer(kind=c_int), value :: ldc

     end subroutine cublasdgemm

  end interface

  do i = 1, N
     do j = 1, N
       x(i, j) = 4.0 * i
       y(i, j) = 3.0 + j
       z(i, j) = 0.0
     end do
  end do

  flag = 'N'

  !$acc data copyin (x, y) copy (z)

  !$acc host_data use_device (x, y, z)
  call cublasdgemm(flag, flag, n, n, n, 1.0_c_double, x, n, y, n, 0.0_c_double, z, n)
  !$acc end host_data

  !$acc end data

  call dgemm(flag, flag, n, n, n, 1.0_c_double, x, n, y, n, 0.0_c_double, z, n)

  write(*, *) z

end program test
```

Unfortunately I get this error.

```
** On entry to DGEMM  parameter number 1 had an illegal value
```

It seems to me that there's some mismatch in the character data type. But I can't figure it out. I put the DGEMM call with the same variables at the end and it works perfectly.

Thanks for any help.

COMPILATION:

To compile this I use gfortran 6.2 compiled based on the instructions at this link

[gfortran with nvptx](https://github.com/olcf/OLCFHack15)

I then copy from

```
/usr/local/cuda/src/
```

the files

```
fortran_common.h
fortran.h
fortran.c
```

and then do

```
gcc -Wall -g -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/src -DCUBLAS_GFORTRAN -c fortran.c
```

to get the fortran.o file for cuBLAS interface.

Then I do

```
gfortran -Wall -g test.f90 fortran.o -fopenacc -foffload=nvptx-none -foffload=-O3 -O3 -o gpu.x -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcublas -lcudart -lblas
```

This the process I used to successfully run the saxpy example in the first link.

Comment: According to the documentation [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm) the first argument to `cublasdgemm` should be some sort of handle rather than the standard `dgemm` transpose option. In other words `cublasdgemm` doesn't have the same interface as `dgemm`. Of course if the `saxpy` version works then this may not be the case.

Comment: Thanks. I had not seen that earlier. On the other hand the fortran.c file has 
    cublasDgemm (transa[0], transb[0], *m, *n, *k, *alpha, A, *lda,
                 B, *ldb, *beta, C, *ldc) And this is the function I assume we are interfacing to. In addition as you noted, the saxpy example works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer was rather simple. I had to add "value" to the definition of the character variables.

```
    subroutine cublasdgemm(transa, transb, m, n, k, alpha, A, lda, B, &
             ldb, beta, C, ldc) bind(c, name="cublasDgemm")
       use iso_c_binding
       character(kind=c_char), value     :: transa, transb
       integer(kind=c_int), value :: m, n, k
       real(c_double), value      :: alpha
       type(*), dimension(*)      :: A
       integer(kind=c_int), value :: lda
       type(*), dimension(*)      :: B
       integer(kind=c_int), value :: ldb
       real(c_double), value      :: beta
       type(*), dimension(*)      :: C
       integer(kind=c_int), value :: ldc

     end subroutine cublasdgemm
```